# Find a chord progression

Tags: piano, chords, chord-progressions, ear-training, chord-voicings

I am looking for the chord progression that appears in [this audio file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/15-Lalo0bfL8AQT4ebbOueGZcwmEFF_Lr/view?usp=sharing).
There should be : G/D - Bm/F# - F#m, but I am missing one. Thanks in advance !

Comment: Please read through the help centre!

Comment: sorry, what is the problem ?

Comment: The question is close to being closed, as this site is not designed to provide answers to questions like this. When you read through the Help Centre, you'll see what is and isn't acceptable as a question. Asking for information like what chord is this is off limits.